# Corned Beef in a slow cooker?

Tags: beef, crockpot

I have my corned beef cooking in my crock pot for about 6 hours on low.  Should the meat be falling apart by now?  It is still one big hunk of meat.  I thought it would be ready in about 1.5 hours.  Should I bump it up to high?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer because I've never made it myself, but I just had corned beef that was slowcooked for over a day and it was delicious!

Comment: Could you explain what kind of liquid set up have the meat in, if any; and what amount of space there is for the meat in the vessel?

Comment: Like mfg said, you need to almost cover the meat in water or broth.  If you cover in liquid it will definitely fall apart

Comment: I always cook corned beef in a crock pot.  I let it go 6-8 hours on low, or 4 hours on high.  The  meat remains a single hunk but when sliced it falls apart easily.

Answer (score 1):

This year, I slow cooked corned beef for about 8 hours in my crock pot.  The slow cooker was set to high for the first 4 hours and set to low for the last 4.  The meat didn't "fall apart" when I took it out, rather it kept its form and allowed me to slice it (against the grain).

I should mention that I had the corned beef submerged in a water/beer mixture during the entire cooking process.  I used 1 bottle of beer (optional) and filled the rest of the slow cooker with water until the beef was submerged.

Answer (score 0):

Any type of Brisket has to be slow cooked either in a slow cooker or in the oven for almost a full working day if not longer…. the longer the better! and on low! Just barely cover with water and the seasoning packet goes on the meat first. If I recall fat side down :) putting one in to cook overnight as I post this :)